# Session problem after logout

Tags: php, session, session-variables

In My web page,I have username and password field ,when user enter correct username and password , it shows index.php . When user click logout link ,it shows login page .But when we click browser back button after logout ,again it goes to last page what we shows .

My logout codes follows

```
<?php

 unset($_SESSION['username']);

 unset($_SESSION['password']);

header("Location: login.php");
```

?>

Comment: you should check session var on evry page

Answer (score 1):

By using the browser's local cache, they're not issuing a new request to you (which would allow you to guide them through login/etc.) You need to control the cacheability of all resources that contain sensitive information. Typically, you can do this via adding Cache-Control headers.

Answer (score 1):

Use this instead on your logout page...

```
session_start();

session_destroy();
```

This will destroy all sessions related to that particular person at that time.

Answer (score 0):

Explicitly prevent caching of resources you need to protect.

Add this to your pages.

```
header("Cache-Control: no-cache, must-revalidate"); // HTTP/1.1
header("Expires: Mon, 26 Jul 1997 05:00:00 GMT"); // Date in the past
```